# How to build gulp css files using TFS (Local builds using Task Runner Explorer)

Tags: css, tfs, gulp

We have the following issue in our build system:
We build an ASP.NET project which has many scss files.. We want to compile them using Gulp.
When working local, no problem, we use the Task Runner Explorer in VS2015 to automate the pre-build event, but, when building using TFS, we don't have access to this tool and thus it leaves us with no css file.

My question is, what would be considered the best way to automate this pre-build event (creating css file using Gulp in TFS2015)?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both VSTS and TFS 2017 you can just add the out-of-the-box Gulp Task to your build and configure it like any other task.

If you have an old version of TFS then you may need to use PowerShell to achieve the same thing:

http://colinsalmcorner.com/post/jspm-npm-gulp-and-webdeploy-in-a-teambuild

You may also want to check the Marketplace for a Build Task for Gulp that you can download: http://marketplace.visualstudio.com

Comment: Thanks for your answer!